# window in eclipse that lists open files

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I'm looking for a way to get a window (like the package explorer) that just lists the files that eclipse has open - ideally like a permanent ctrl-e, or ctrl-F6.

I was thinking this might be possible with some kind of configuration of mylyn. Currently when I have the package explorer in 'context focus' mode, it lists the entities I'm interested in but provides too much detail; I'd like to hide the method and class elements.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: You can also use CTRL+SHIFT+E to get a slightly more stable dialog of the currently open editors.  But you have to dismiss it to do anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't give you exactly what you're asking for, but it might work for you. You can get mylyn to only show you the files and not their structural contents.

In the package window, select filters from the drop-down. Exclude all the java things you don't want. Then switch the mylyn context filter on for the package window. You now have only the files visible in the current context excluding all the usual expanded structural information.

Comment: For the Java Package Explorer, there's an easier way: Just go to _Preferences -> Java -> Appearance_ and unchek _Show members in Package Explorer_. Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062931/eclipse-how-to-disable-outline-tree-view-for-files/25063350#25063350) for more details.