# Eclipse: How to disable outline tree view for files?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to disable the **outline tree view** for files in Eclipse?

[image: Image showing Eclipse tree view for files]

I never use it (on purpose at least) and find it to be quite distracting. (I prefer <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.)

Comment: why don't you close it?

Comment: @sina72 What should I close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the *Java Package Explorer*, there is an option for this in the Preferences:

Go to *Preferences -> Java -> Appearance* and un-check 'Show members in Package Explorer'.

[image: option from preferences for hiding members in package explorer]

---

Alternatively, most of Eclipse's different navigator views offer the ability to *Filter* what to display. Click on the small triangular "menu" symbol at the top of the view and select "Customize View", or "Filter", depending on the view. You are then presented with a menu where you call select what to show and what to hide.

[image: generic 'customize view' menu entry]

This works with the *Java Package Explorer*, *Project Explorer*, the general *Navigator* and also with the *PyDev Package Explorer* View, and probably a few more. This is a bit more manual, but allows for a finer adjustment. (Options what to show and what to hide differ between the different views.)

Answer (score 0):

The creator of [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) commented on my [bug report](https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/427) and this is how you do it:

1. Select the PyDev perspective and then the Package Explorer (if not already).
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>
3. Click on `Customize View`.
4. Select `PyDev: Nodes: All`
5. Press `OK`.